# Net 2.0 Framework Service Pack 2 Issue

Tags: .net, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to install .Net 2.0 Framework Service Pack 2 on a Win 2k8 server which currently has .Net Framework 2.0 SP1, .Net Framework 3.0 SP 2 and .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 installed. The reason for installing SP2 is that I need to install a hotfix for this issue (hanselman.com/blog/…).
When I attempt to install the relevant hotfix it tells me nothing on the machine requires it, but this is not the case. The older definition files are still present. I am able to install on a second machine with the only difference being the lack of an SP2 for .Net 2.0, which is one of the pre-requisities.

When I try to run the SP 2 installer it immediately ends and displays a screen with Setup Error. No other information is shown. If I check the event viewer it shows a single related Information entry saying “Product: Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 -- Installation completed successfully.” Having checked the Installed Updates/Programs I know this is not the case.

Any ideas what could cause this or how to debug?

Answer (score 1):

3.5 SP1 already includes all the updates that 2.0 SP2 would install.  So there's nothing to do, as you can tell.  You don't have a problem.

Comment: The reason for installing SP2 is that I need to install a hotfix for this issue (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx). When I attempt to install the relevant hotfix it tells me nothing on the machine requires it, but this is not the case. The older definition files are still present. I am able to install on a second machine with the only difference being the lack of an SP2 for .Net 2.0, which is one of the pre-requisities.

Comment: Sigh, another lovely XY question.  Click the Ask Question button and this time ask the *real* question you want to ask.  Ask X, how to get that hotfix installed.  And mention that installing SP2 didn't help.